# Splitting of Big File into Smaller Chunks in Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, split, csplit

I need to split the bigger file into smaller chunks based on the last occurrence of the pattern in the bigger file using shell script. For eg.

Sample.txt ( File will be sorted based on the third field on which pattern to be searched )

```
NORTH EAST|0004|00001|Fost|Weaather|<br/> 
NORTH EAST|0004|00001|Fost|Weaather|<br/> 
SOUTH|0003|00003|Haet|Summer|<br/> 
SOUTH|0003|00003|Haet|Summer|<br/> 
SOUTH|0003|00003|Haet|Summer|<br/> 
EAST|0007|00016|uytr|kert|<br/> 
EAST|0007|00016|uytr|kert|<br/> 
WEST|0002|00112|WERT|fersg|<br/> 
WEST|0002|00112|WERT|fersg|<br/>
SOUTHWEST|3456|01134|GDFSG|EWRER|<br/>
```

"Pattern 1 = 00003 " to be searched output file must contain sample_00003.txt

```
NORTH EAST|0004|00001|Fost|Weaather|<br/> 
NORTH EAST|0004|00001|Fost|Weaather|<br/>
SOUTH|0003|00003|Haet|Summer|<br/> 
SOUTH|0003|00003|Haet|Summer|<br/> 
SOUTH|0003|00003|Haet|Summer|<br/>
```

"Pattren 2 = 00112" to be searched output file must contain sample_00112.txt

```
EAST|0007|00016|uytr|kert|<br/> 
EAST|0007|00016|uytr|kert|<br/> 
WEST|0002|00112|WERT|fersg|<br/> 
WEST|0002|00112|WERT|fersg|<br/>
```

Used

```
awk -F'|' -v 'pattern="00003"' '$3~pattern big_file' > smallfile
```

and grep commands but it was very time consuming since file is 300+ MB of size.

Comment: What do you mean by "the last occurrence of the pattern"?

Comment: Last time the pattern matches in the file. I.e Pattern "00003" matches till 5th line of sample.txt file in its third field. So process want to split it out till that 5th line into an separate file.

Comment: In the future, please use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. 
 Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you'll find a faster tool than `awk`, but here's a variant that fixes your own attempt and also speeds things up a little by using *string* matching rather than *regex* matching.

It processes lookup values in a loop, and outputs everything from where the previous iteration left off through the *last* occurrence of the value at hand to a file named `smallfile<n>`, where `<n>` is an index starting with `1`.

```
ndx=0; fromRow=1
for val in '00003' '00112' '|'; do  # 2 sample values to match, plus dummy value
  chunkFile="smallfile$(( ++ndx ))"
  fromRow=$(awk -F'|' -v fromRow="$fromRow" -v outFile="$chunkFile" -v val="$val" '
    NR < fromRow { next }
    { if ($3 != val) { if (p) { print NR; exit } } else { p=1 } } { print > outFile }
  ' big_file)
done
```

Note that dummy value `|` ensures that any *remaining* rows after the last true value to match are saved to a chunk file too.

---

Note that moving all the logic into a single `awk` script should be much faster, because `big_file` would only have to be read *once*:

```
awk -F'|' -v vals='00003|00112' '
  BEGIN { split(vals, val); outFile="smallfile" ++ndx }
  { 
    if ($3 != val[ndx]) { 
      if (p) { p=0; close(outFile); outFile="smallfile" ++ndx } 
    } else { 
      p=1 
    } 
    print > outFile
  }
' big_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Perl:

```
 perl -ne '/00003/ && print' big_file > small_file
```

and compare its timing with other solutions...

**EDIT**

Limiting my answer to the tools you didn't try already... you can also use:

```
sed -n '/00003/p' big_file > small_file
```

But I tend to believe perl will be faster. Again... I'd suggest you to measure the elapsed for different solutions on your own.

Comment: @mklement0: I guess you tested the performance of these "flawed attempts" before commenting...

Comment: I think you misunderstood, so let me try to explain it differently: The OP described a problem and also included an _attempt_ at a solution (the `awk` command). 
That attempt is _technically_ flawed, but more importantly, it is _fundamentally conceptually flawed_ - even if fixed, the attempt would not solve the problem.
Your answer contains _technically_ correct commands that are the equivalent of the conceptually flawed attempt and therefore do not solve the OP's problem.